# Is there any way to have public static variable with remember state in jetpack compose (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun Main() {
    var cardsList: List<String> by remember { mutableStateOf( listOf("Test1","Test2") ) }

    Column(
        Cards()
    )
}

@Composable
fun Cards() {
    for(item in cardsList) {
        Button(
            onClick = {cardsList -= item}
        )
    }
}
```

This is my code, I need to re-assign the 'cardsList' out side of main function, also if 'cardsList' changed i want UI and all functions that use 'cardsList' as parameter refresh too

can a class help me? maybe i put my list in a class

I tried code below but didnt work

```
var cardsList: List<String> = listOf("Test1","Test2")

@Composable
fun Main() {
    Column(
        Cards()
    )
}

@Composable
fun Cards() {
    for(item in cardsList) {
        Button(
            onClick = {cardsList -= item}
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You should pass the list as an argument to the `Cards` Composable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved with [state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting):

```
@Composable fun Main() {
    var cardsList: List<String> by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf("Test1", "Test2")) }
    Cards(
        cards = cardsList,
        onCardClick = { card -> cardsList -= card }
    )
}

@Composable fun Cards(
    cards: List<String>
    onCardClick: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    for(item in cards) {
        Button(
            onClick = { onCardClick(item) }
        ) { Text(text = item) }
    }
}
```

If you have more such variables or you just prefer it that way, you can create a state class:

```
class MainState {
   var cardsList by mutableStateOf(listOf("Test1", "Test2"))
       private set

   fun removeCard(card: String) {
       cardsList -= card
   }
}

@Composable fun Main() {
    val state = remember { MainState() }
    Cards(state = state)
}

@Composable fun Cards(state: MainState) {
    for(item in state.cardsList) {
        Button(
            onClick = { state.removeCard(item) }
        ) { Text(text = item) }
    }
}
```